# Understanding CSS syntax, & + &

Tags: css, css-selectors, ampersand

I'm looking at the following selector from a .css file:

```
.tab {

    flex: 1 0 auto;
    height: 52px;

    & + & {
        border-left: 1px solid;
    }

}
```

I'm not familiar with the syntax of `& + & {}` - what does it mean?

Comment: That code is not native CSS. Look into CSS preprocessors.

Answer (score 18):

This is not CSS but some file meant to be compiled to CSS. It's probably SCSS or Less.

In [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/) and [Less](http://lesscss.org/), the `&` is just a repetition of the enclosing selector.

So

```
& + & {
    border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

would be translated as

```
.tab + .tab {
    border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

This construct is common when you need to add a border between items: you add it to the left of any items which follows another one.

[introduction to the sass/less ampersand](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/)